# plot hold on in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot

I am new to matlab and need a bit of help with a gui. I have two axes boxes (axes2 and axes3) where I use checkmarks to plot within. First checkbox creates two plots: one (x1,y1) in axes2 and the second (x1,ht) in axes3. The second checkbox also creates two plots: one(x2,y2) in axes2 and the second (x2,ht2) in axes3. I want to Hold on to the figures, so if I select both checkmarks both axes2 and axes3 will contain two plots. However, only axes2 work. In axes3 only show the plot connected to the last selected chechmark.

Please help. The code is below:

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 if get(handles.checkbox1,'Value')
 hold on;
 handles.hCbox1Plot = plot(x1,y1,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);
 hold on;
 handles.hCbox2Plot = plot(x1,ht,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [0 0 0],'parent',handles.axes3);
 guidata(hObject,handles);  % do this to save the updated handles structure
 else
  if ~isempty(handles.hCbox1Plot);
     ~isempty(handles.hCbox2Plot);
      delete(handles.hCbox1Plot);
      delete(handles.hCbox2Plot);
  end
 end

function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 if get(handles.checkbox2,'Value')
 hold on;
 handles.hCbox3Plot = plot(x2,y2,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [1 0 0],'parent',handles.axes2);
 hold on;
 handles.hCbox4Plot = plot(x2,ht2,'LineWidth',2,'Color', [1 0 0],'parent',handles.axes3);
 guidata(hObject,handles);  % do this to save the updated handles structure
 else
  if ~isempty(handles.hCbox3Plot);
     ~isempty(handles.hCbox4Plot);
      delete(handles.hCbox3Plot);
      delete(handles.hCbox4Plot);
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:

hold( handles.axes2, 'on' )